# How to read multiple inputs separated by space in a single line in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read multiple inputs in python separated by space. All of them are integers, float or double. Is there a way to get that done in python 3.8

Comment: `input().split(" ")`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
var = input.split(" ")
```

Above code will create an array of string.

for eg given input **1 2 3 4 5** , it'll create an array of var with elements ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

Note that the above code will store each element as a string. If you want to change the data type of the elements you can use map function.

```
var_integers = list(map(int, input.split()))
```

This'll create an array of integer. Taking above example of **1 2 3 4 5**, it'll create an array var_integers with elements [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

You can use any function in place of **int** in **map** function to transform the iterable (here input().split() creates a list of string elements as stated above which acts as an iterable) passed as a second argument.

For example if you use **float** instead of **int** then the input string will be converted to float then stored in array.

You can also store the elements directly into variable instead of storing in an array by:

```
var1, var2, var3 .. ,varn = map(int, input().split())
```

Here you have to specify exact number of variables as the number of elements separated by space in the input string.